# Title for Containers?

Tags: fields

I'm trying to add a title to a container. I've created the following:

[image]

However, I would like to have a title like this, for example:

[image]

Is there a default CSS class that I could use? Currently, I've wrapped a table with a div of

`class="crm-tabset ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround under the 'Membership' section:

[image]